# Elixir script load all modules in folder recursivelly

Tags: elixir

I want to compile and load all modules recursivelly in specific folder.
I know I can do this with Mix project

```
iex -S mix run
```

Which will load all files in `lib/` directory.

However I want the same behaviour in non-Mix script - programmaticly if it's possible.
Something like `Code.compile_all("directory/")`
Is there any API like that?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Just to clarify the terms: Mix does not load the files in lib/, it compiles them if needed, and then uses the compiled byte code (without having to execute the whole file again).

You can load any file in a directory by calling `Code.require_file/1` or `Code.load_file/1` but that does not generate any artifact in disk. If later on you call `Code.require_file/1`, the same files will be evaluated again, which may take time. The idea of compiling is exactly so you don't pay this price every time.

That said, let's answer your question directly.

1. A way to load everything in a directory is:

   ```
   dir
   |> Path.join("**/*.exs")
   |> Path.wildcard()
   |> Enum.map(&Code.require_file/1)
   ```
2. If you want to compile them, use:

   ```
   dir
   |> Path.join("**/*.ex")
   |> Path.wildcard()
   |> Kernel.ParallelCompiler.files_to_path("path/for/beam/files")
   ```
3. If you want to just compile another directory in the context of a project (with a mix.exs and what not), you can give any directory you want to Mix inside `def project`:

   ```
   elixirc_paths: ["lib", "my/other/path"]
   ```

That's it.

Comment: Thanks @Jose. I see You don't even sleep just to help Your community :)

Comment: Thanks José! This saved my bacon.

Comment: Hey @Jose I've tried using Method #3 in `mix.exs` of a Phoenix project to hotload a dir within the `lib` folder (eg `lib/new_namespace`). However, Elixir doesn't seem to be loading/compiling the modules I've defined in that folder. I get an error message `** (UndefinedFunctionError) function NewNamespace.ModuleName.test/0 is undefined (module NewNamespace.ModuleName is not available)
    NewNamespace.ModuleName.test()`. I was wondering if you could point in the right direction of how to resolve this, the right way. I've been using `Code.require_file` but that seems like the wrong way to do it

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about built-in ways to do this in Elixir, but you could achieve the same result using something like [`filelib:fold_files/5`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/filelib.html#fold_files-5) from Erlang.

```
:filelib.fold_files "directory/", "\.ex$", true, &Code.load_file/1, []
```